# How to Pass values javascript onclick to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this this image with onclick function on it

```
<img id='1213' src='img/heart.png' onclick='heart(this.id)'>
```

which to call this function :

```
function heart(id) {
    $('#heart').dialog('open');
    return false;
}
```

How can i show the ID inside the div?

```
<div id="heart">
     Name : ABC
     ID : The ID need to be here 
</div>
```

P/S : i have reason why i want to use the onclick instead directly using the jquery get val from the image id directly.

Comment: You absolutely never, *never*, **never** use inline event handlers (like `onclick`) when you have jQuery.

Comment: `$('#heart').html(id).dialog('open');`

Comment: Use `$( "#heart" ).on( "click",function(){ });` instead of inline html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should use JavaScript to attach your events. You've already included jQuery, so we may as well use that. Once you attach the event, you can use the `text()` method to set the innerText property of the `span` within the target div. Try this:

```
<img id="1213" class="heart" src="img/heart.png" />

<div id="heart">
     Name : ABC
     ID : <span></span>
</div>
```

```js
$('.heart').click(function() {
    $('#heart span').text(this.id).dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To show image id, You can use

```
$('#heart').html(id).dialog('open');
```

I would recommend you not to use ugly inline event handler. You can bind event using jQuery. Here I have added a CSS class to `img` element then we can use [`Class Selector $(".class")`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind event

*HTML*

```
<img class="myImage" id='1213' src='img/heart.png'>
```

*Script*

```
$(function() {          
    $('.myImage').on('click', function(){
        $('#heart').html(this.id).dialog('open'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```js
function heart(id) {
  $('#heart').text(id).dialog();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<img id='1213' src='img/heart.png' onclick='heart(this.id);'>


<div id="heart">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, you could make use of data-* attribute.

```
<img id="someid" src="img/heart.png" data-id="1213"/>

    $('#someid').click(function(e) {
        var id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
        $('#heart').text(id).dialog('open');
    });
```